# Docusaurus baseUrl issues with Static Hosting Vercel and Netlify

Tags: reactjs, netlify, vercel, docusaurus, trailing-slash

we are trying to build our documentation website with docusaurus. We are closed to launch our product. But we are facing problems with the deployment. We are trying to host the website with vercel. The problem we are stated below.

We configured Docusaurus baseUrl to `/en/` and deployed to vercel. Locally it builds completely fine.
But on vercel we are getting

Your Docusaurus site did not load properly.
A very common reason is a wrong site [baseUrl configuration](https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus.config.js/#baseurl).
Current configured `baseUrl = /en/`
We suggest trying `baseUrl = /`

Also, it looks like when I did go to the `site/en/` vercel is trying to find everything on `build/en/` folder.
But if I change the build directory to `build/en/`, it looking of `build/en/en/`.
I tried to search through github issues, tried few things. Nothing worked.
Any help or insights will be appreciated.

Here is my **docusaurus.config.js**

```js
const config = {
  title: 'Agora Documentation',
  tagline:
    'Agora SDKs  is built for Live, interactive voice and video powered by the only global network dedicated to real-time engagement at ease.',
  url: process.env.URL, // https://docs-test-q239acpv9-agora-gdxe.vercel.app/
  baseUrl: process.env.BASE_PATH,  // /en/
  trailingSlash: false,
...
```

Link: https://docs-test-q239acpv9-agora-gdxe.vercel.app/
[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the url and the base url directly into the `docusaurus.config.js` file instead from a `.env` file? Or can you run the production build of your website locally and paste the terminal output here, if it shows any errors or warnings?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?